# Googles sites is not appearing when searched

Tags: google-sites

I created a website in google sites and when I search the site is doesn't appear. My domain is with godaddy ,I connected the cname and forwarding on my own and then removed it and did it again with one of their techs and its still not working. Each time I created a change I republished the site and waited 48 hours. when you search the site the error refused to connect appears, my website is Dreamfull.net.